# Applescript to open specific Terminal Style Windows

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, terminal, applescript

Ok, so the thing is. I want to have different style terminal windows for each job. Each one will have a different job, i.e. , one will connect through ssh to a site, other window to other place, etc.

So I guess this could be done with some Applescripting?

The thing would be to have some applescripts that opens a different terminal window. And then add each applescript to a shortcut.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Duplicate (though not obvious): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794050/applescript-to-open-named-terminal-window

Answer (score 3):

How about setting up a Window group in terminal ?

Open all Terminal windows you want --> Shell --> Show Inspector. Under Settings you can change the theme of each terminal window.

Window --> Save Windows as Group

In preferences set the startup option to display the group.

http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/9681/screenshot20111018at110.png
http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/9681/screenshot20111018at110.png

If you want to use Applescript to set a window's theme you first need to get the id's of all the themes you have using this applescript :

```
set a to {}
tell application "Terminal"
    repeat with i from 1 to count settings set
        set temp to {settings set i's name, settings set i's id}
        set end of a to temp
    end repeat
    a
end tell
```

This will output an array of id # and the theme's name. Next to create a new window use the following :

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set a to do script "" -- creates new window
    set a's current settings to (settings set id <one of the id #>)
end tell
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. But I won't be using them at the same time. So I need to open each one differently.

Comment: Actually (at least in OS X 10.8), you can reference settings sets by *name*; e.g.: `set a's current settings to settings set "Grass"`. Also, while applying settings *after* tab creation works, it only does so with respect to the *visual*, not the *behavioral* attributes, such as the `When the shell exits:` setting in `Preferences > Settings > Shell`. Sadly, Terminal's AppleScript support doesn't support creating a window (or tab) with specific settings as a single command.

Answer (score 3):

`tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to click menu bar 1's menu bar item "Shell"'s menu 1's menu item "New Window"'s menu 1's menu item "Grass"`

---

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set win to do script
    set win's current settings to settings set "Basic"
end tell
```

Comment: Great solutions; to make the GUI scripting locale-independent, use `tell application "System Events" to tell menu 1 of menu item 1 of menu 1 of menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1 of application process "Terminal" to click menu item "Grass"` (while this relies on positions, in this particular case it's reasonable to assume they won't change; note that settings names are *not* localized). Caveat re 2nd sol.: applying settings *after* tab creation works, but only with respect to the *visual*, not *behavioral* attributes, such as the `When the shell exits:` setting in `Preferences > Settings > Shell`.